# How to always use the base class and ignore STI in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

I have a module that I'm including in several models with this content:

```
self.class.find_by_foo(bar)
```

Everything was fine until I started using STI. That line should always generate the query

```
select * from table where foo=bar"
```

and **not**

```
select * from table where foo=bar AND type="Whatever"
```

Is there a simple way to avoid it?

I though of two solutions. Walking up the class hierarchy until I find the top-most class before `ActiveRecord::Base` or run the query by hand, like:

```
self.class.find_by_sql("select * from #{self.class.table_name} where foo=bar")
```

I don't like either solution. Is there a better one?

Answer (score 29):

First, you can always get to the base class with the method base_class:

```
self.class.base_class.find_by_foo(bar)
```

However, in your example above, you shouldn't have to access the base class.  You can just do the following and Rails will know the correct table name:

```
self.class.where(:foo => bar)
```

There are actually very few cases when you need to access the base class.

Comment: In Rails 4 `self.class` unexpectedly returned the objects parent class, in Rails 5 `self.class` returns, as excepted, the models class. `self.class.base_class` can be used to get the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

Until there's a better answer, I'm using this code to find the base class of the STI chain:

```
klass = self.class
self.class.ancestors.each do |k|
  if k == ActiveRecord::Base
    break # we reached the bottom of this barrel
  end
  if k.is_a? Class
    klass = k
  end
end
```